# Changing status of a discord.py Bot when a user enters a specific voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm looking to make a bot come online whenever a user joins a channel and go offline when a user leaves a channel. I'm quite new to discord.py but here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.offline)
    print("Bot ready")

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if not before.channel:
        if after.channel.id == [""Channel ID 1""] or after.channel.id == [""Channel ID 2""]:
                await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="users | Ready to mute"))
                print(f'{member.name} joined {after.channel.name}')
    elif before.channel and after.channel:
        if before.channel != after.channel:
            if after.channel.id == [""Channel ID 1""] or after.channel.id == [""Channel ID 2""]:
                if member.roles[1].name == "Admin" or member.roles[1].name == "Moderator":
                    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="users | Ready to mute"))
                    print(f'{member.name} joined {after.channel.name}')
    elif before.channel and not after.channel:
            if member.roles[1].name == "Admin" or member.roles[1].name == "Moderator":
                await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.offline)
                print(f'{member.name} left {before.channel.name}')

client.run("Key")
```

I will, of course, replace ""Channel ID 1"" & ""Channel ID 2"" with the channel IDs and ""Key" with my authentication key.

The problem that I am having is that the events don't seem to be registered.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A couple of changes, `id` is an int not a string as explained [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=textchannel%20id#discord.VoiceChannel.id). So you should be comparing `channel.id` against an integer, not a list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A couple of changes, id is an int not a string as explained here. So
> you should be comparing channel.id against an integer, not a list
> item.

– InsertCheesyLine